# How to close selenium browser in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I have this code:

```
def process(line):
    driver.get(line) # open browser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool() # Create a multiprocessing Pool
    with open('file.txt') as data_inputs:
        pool.map(process, data_inputs)
        driver.close() # i want close browser from here
```

inside `file.txt` is lists of url

I know tahat I can close browser after `driver.get(line)` , but I want to close browser after multiprocessing pool.

Is this possible  ?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have two options:

```
driver.quit()
```

This closes the current tab you are on

Or you could use

```
driver.close()
```

This closes all tabs currently opened by the web driver.

Comment: That's not correct. These methods have the opposite [meaning](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=driver%20close#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.quit).